# How To Check If First Character Is In Specific Positions Of Input "C"

Tags: c, string, input, while-loop, char

I am working on a program that takes a user given input of any length and checks to see if the first character of that input (*before the space*) is **within the 10th - 16th position** input of that same string, then if the character is within the 10th - 16th position it will echo the input (*after the space*).

**Current Code**

```
# include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int in;
                                                          
    in = getchar();
    while (in != '\n'){                                       
        putchar(in);

        in = getchar();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This code will get me input of any size and echo it back.. Where I am having trouble is **traversing** the input and checking whether the first character is in the 10th - 16th character of the input. I have tried using pointers to no avail because I don't know how to do it without using a string I can't use a string only because a string requires me to enter a length which in this circumstance a set length is not allowed.

**Current Input & Output**

```
>f 012r4g67f
f 012r4g67f

>a 012345678a
a 012345678a
```

**Correct Input & Output**

```
>f 012r4g67f
```

*Nothing Should Be Echoed Because 'f' is not within 10 - 16*

```
>a 012345678a
012345678a
```

*Everything after space is echoed as a is within the first 10 - 16 characters*

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 ways to go through the user inputs :

- you read while looping through getchar and use if to analyse the char returned
- you store getchar returns into an array in order to manipulate the content

Comment: How would I go about storing the getchar() returns into an array? and then traversing the array? I'm a little new to C so I don't know if this question is rudimentary.

Comment: you need to know [how to use arrays](https://beginnersbook.com/2014/01/c-arrays-example/) and then after you've set up the right size for your string you could something like that `array[index] = c` c is your char that stores one be one getchar return